# Why can't my Linux kernel reclaim its slab memory?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, low-memory

I have a system that suffered from ever-increasing memory usage until it hit the point where it was hitting swap even for mundane things and consequently becoming pretty unresponsive.  The culprit appears to have been kernel-allocated memory, but I'm having difficulty figuring out what exactly was going on in the kernel.

How can I tell which kernel threads/modules/whatever are responsible for particular chunks of kernel memory usage?

Here's a graph of the system's memory usage over time:

[image: System memory usage; slab_unrecl grows over time]

The `slab_unrecl` value, which grows over time, corresponds to the `SUnreclaim` field in `/proc/meminfo`.

When I ran `slabtop` towards the end of that graph and sorted it by cache size, here's what it showed me:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 15451251 / 15530002 (99.5%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 399651 / 399651 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 85 / 113 (75.2%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 2394126.21K / 2416458.60K (99.1%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.16K / 18.62K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
3646503 3646503 100%    0.38K 173643       21   1389144K kmem_cache
3852288 3851906  99%    0.06K  60192       64    240768K kmalloc-64
3646656 3646656 100%    0.06K  56979       64    227916K kmem_cache_node
1441760 1441675  99%    0.12K  45055       32    180220K kmalloc-128
499136 494535  99%    0.25K  15598       32    124784K kmalloc-256
1066842 1066632  99%    0.09K  25401       42    101604K kmalloc-96
101430 101192  99%    0.19K   4830       21     19320K kmalloc-192
 19168  17621  91%    1.00K    599       32     19168K kmalloc-1024
  8386   7470  89%    2.00K    525       16     16800K kmalloc-2048
 15000   9815  65%    1.05K    500       30     16000K ext4_inode_cache
 66024  45955  69%    0.19K   3144       21     12576K dentry
369536 369536 100%    0.03K   2887      128     11548K kmalloc-32
 18441  16586  89%    0.58K    683       27     10928K inode_cache
 44331  42665  96%    0.19K   2111       21      8444K cred_jar
 12208   7529  61%    0.57K    436       28      6976K radix_tree_node
   627    580  92%    9.12K    209        3      6688K task_struct
  6720   6328  94%    0.65K    280       24      4480K proc_inode_cache
 36006  36006 100%    0.12K   1059       34      4236K kernfs_node_cache
266752 266752 100%    0.02K   1042      256      4168K kmalloc-16
134640 133960  99%    0.02K    792      170      3168K fsnotify_mark_connector
  1568   1461  93%    2.00K     98       16      3136K mm_struct
  1245   1165  93%    2.06K     83       15      2656K sighand_cache
```

Conclusions:

- The kernel's slab allocator is using about 2.3 GB of RAM
- Almost all of that is unreclaimable
- About 1.3 GB of it is occupied by the `kmem_cache` cache
- Another 0.5 GB belongs to the various-sized kmalloc caches

This is where I've hit a wall.  I haven't figured out how to look inside those caches and see why they've gotten so large (or why their memory is unreclaimable).  How can I go further in my investigations?

Answer (score 4):

`perf kmem record --slab`  will capture profiling data and  `perf kmem stat --slab --caller` will subtotal by kernel symbol.

That doesn't explain why your workload does this however. Add in `perf record`  and look at the report to see what is calling into the kernel.

kprobes can trace specific kernel stacks leading to a type of allocation. I'm not super familiar with this myself, but try reading the [examples accompanying eBPF scripts like slabratetop](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/slabratetop_example.txt).

Also vary things up a bit on your host. Add RAM to be sure you are not under sizing it. Try newer kernel versions or a different distribution.